# What pH sensor have a long-term use with non-calibrated?

Tags: sensor, underwater, ph

I have a project that use some water monitoring sensors (pH, oxygen, conductivity...). But my project are facing a problem:

My device can not be touch within 3 months. And as my knowledge, those sensor above need to be calibrated after a short period of time.

So, any solution for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are industrial self-cleaning double junction probes that will operate for 6-18 months.

They will be more expensive than cheap lab probes.

Comment: An alternative is putting the sensor into a tube, rinse the fluid into it, do the measurement, then rinse with distilled water. Needs three solenoid valves. If a measurement cycle is over months, I doubt it's more than two or three measurements per day needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the alkalinity is somewhat static, and the precision requirement not exact, you can ballpark calculate PH based on CO2.

You can build an underwater CO2 probe using off the shelf air measurement devices and ptfe membranes, or buy one of the commercial offerings available for this.